# How to register a .UK domain name in USA

Tags: domains, domain-registration, top-level-domains

I am hoping to register a .UK domain name.  However, I am based in the USA.  What's the best procedure to get a UK address for registering the .UK extension?  Are there commonly-used services that provide mailing addresses in UK for this purpose?

Also, is anyone aware of any "gotachas" that I should watch out for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anyone can register .uk domain names on a first-come, first-served basis, but an address for service in the United Kingdom will be
>   required for registrants who live overseas.     *This address must be
>   listed as the admin contact for your domain name.*     This
>   requirement does not apply for .co.uk and .org.uk domain names. [Source](https://au.godaddy.com/help/about-uk-domains-5854)

So you only need a UK address for the admin contact for .UK domains.  I have been working with domains for nearly 20 years and I have yet to have anyone attempt to contact me via the Admin, Billing or Tech contacts.

Given that forwarding services charge you on a usage basis, if you set up an address with one of them, it is unlikely to ever be used and if it is, then it must be *really* important and worth paying a few (insert currency unit here) for.

Comment: Any suggestions for a forwarding service that doesn't charge setup fees?

Comment: Google is your friend...

Comment: Yes I know... just wondering if you had any personal recommendations that were already tried and tested.

Comment: Nope, never done it, have nothing to do with the UK, just did some research ;o)